# How to recursively check for CTRL+M characters

Tags: unix

How to recursively check for CTRL+M characters from the parent directory and remove it in Unix ?

Comment: Do you mean carriage return (`\r`) in the file/directory names? What on Earth are they doing there?:)

Answer (score 2):

**If you meant the ^M are in the file and/or directory names and you want to remove those files and directories:**

That's nearly trivial using find.

The only tricky bit is how to enter CTRL-M characters on the command line: first type CTRL-V (to escape the shell form interpreting the next keystroke) and the CTRL-M

so

`find .. -name '*^M*' -print`

[read above on how to type the ^M]

will list all it would take
and

`` find .. -depth -name `*^M*' -exec rm -rf {} \; ``

would remove them all (recursively if it's a directory - if you want directories and files treated separately, that too is possible (using -type f and/or -type d)

The -depth makes find recurse (do it for the children) before it does it for the rectory itself (removes some error conditions)

**If you meant the ^M are in the filenames and you want to rename those files:**

The basic find construct above remains the same, but we need to call something that renames the directory or file instead of removing it.

Also removing the ^M from a parent directory is trickier than it might seem, so we need to make sure we move from the bottom of the tree (the files) first and not rename the directories till we're done with all the children.
Also if the directory needs to rename we need to rename it when we're just dealign with the directory itself, and not already do that while dealing with the files in it.

So let's make a small script and name it /tmp/rename
It'll take the filename as a parameter and rename that file (or directory).

`` #/bin/sh
OLD=$1
PTH=`echo $OLD | sed 's/^\(.*\)\/[^\/]*$/\1/'`
FLE=`echo $OLD | sed 's/^.*\/\([^\/]*\)$/\1/'`
NEW=`echo $FLE | sed 's/^M//g'`
echo mv $OLD $PTH/$NEW ``

[again: the ^M should be typed as the control character in the editor while escaping it's meaning from the editor (e.g. in vi that means typing it as CTRL-V CTRL-M)]

To make it a bit more foolproof: it's best to add a test to see if $new exists as it would overwrite those without warning as it is now.
[left as an exercise for the reader for now]

So first we call this for directories only and we do a depth first:

`find .. -depth -exec /tmp/rename {} \;`

That should rename all the files and directories, depth first (that's rather important for more complex situations).

**If you meant the ^M are in the files themselves and you want to remove those:**

sed can be used to remove ^M characters easily using the following command for a single stream: `sed 's/^M//g'` . But to do this in-place and for a file tree it requires creating temporary files (and/or backup files) if you want to use sed.

So on to ex to do it in-place.

First create the command file. Let's put it in **/tmp/commands** and give it the following content:

`%s/^M//g
wq`

Again: you need to escape the ^M from the editor you're using (it it's vi that's CTRL-V to escape the next keystroke from the editor -just like on the command line-)

- The first line substitutes (s) all occurances (g)  on all lines (%)
  of ^M with nothing
- The second lines writes the file after editing
  it.

Next we create a small script to execute the commands using ex. Let's put it in **/tmp/script** and give it the following content:

`#!/bin/sh
cat /tmp/commands | ex -s $1`

The script then needs to be made executable:

`chmod +x /tmp/script`

Now you run this through find:

`find .. -type f -exec /tmp/script {} \;`

Be careful with automating things that change stuff in-place: it's pretty easy to let it escape too far.

Why do we use the script instead of giving find the `cat | ex` construct: escaping the construct to have find see only one command is rather tricky to do and involves invoking a shell anyway, so might as well make it easier to understand without all the escaping (and feels far too advanced given the question).